a list of elements versus a list comprising elements
claim 1
a method comprising:
a) identifying a list of elements having some condition in a database;

As I understand it, "a list of" is equivalent to "a list consisting of", which means that the list only contains the specified elements.
So would a competitor bypass infringement of claim 1 if their implementation identifies a list that also includes other elements not having said "some condition"?
claim 2
a method comprising:
a) identifying a list comprising elements having some condition in a database;

Would claim 1 fix this?


So would a competitor bypass infringement of claim 1 if their implementation identifies a list that also includes other elements not having said "some condition"?

Yes, and this must be so. Otherwise, if you claim that the list can be a superset of the elements having the condition, the claim would be anticipated by prior art that dumps and sends the whole database, which is presumably old and known.

So claim 2 in my post would be invalid?

_Bear: First of all it's rare to see comprising at that place in a claim, so it's not easy to know the meaning of such a claim. But I think it would be trivially anticipated, if it has the meaning you want it to have.
